# toPrimitive gives different results for template literal and string literal

Tags: javascript

I wonder why template string results `[object Object]` in this case:

```
class Omg {}

const omg = new Omg()

Omg.prototype.valueOf = () => 6;

+omg
// 6
omg + ''
// "6"
'' + omg
// "6"
`${omg}`
// "[object Object]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Template strings evidently use `Object.toString()` to 'translate' the placeholders (`${...}`) within it. Template strings are wonderful little beasts ;) If you preferably need `valueOf` in a template string, a `tag function` may be an idea for that (see snippet, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

```js
class Omg {}

const omg = new Omg()

Omg.prototype.valueOf = () => 6;
console.log(+omg)
console.log(omg + '');
console.log('' + omg);
console.log(`${omg}`);
// note: 7 to demo the tag function
Omg.prototype.toString = () => 7; 
console.log(`${omg}`);

// you can use a tag function to force use of valueOf
function useValueOfWherePossible(strings, ...placeHolders) {
  let result = strings.raw[0];
  for (const [i, phldr] of placeHolders.entries()) {
    result += (phldr.valueOf() || phldr) + strings.raw[i + 1];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(useValueOfWherePossible `${omg}`);
```